# Assigning user-determined coordinates to a nested array

Tags: c, arrays, coordinates, nested-loops, multidimensional-array

I have two integers, **range1** and **range2**, and a nested integer array **distance[][]**.

I also have two integer arrays, **elasticity[]** and **resistance[]**, both containing a group of user-determined values. The aforementioned **range1** is equal to the length of **elasticity[]**, whilst **range2** is equal to the length of **resistance[]**.

What I'm trying to do is set each location in **distance[][]** to a specific "coordinate". As an example, assume range1 = 2 and range2 = 3:

```
    distance[0][0] = elasticity[0] * resistance[0];
    distance[0][1] = elasticity[0] * resistance[1];
    distance[0][2] = elasticity[0] * resistance[2];
    distance[1][0] = elasticity[1] * resistance[0];
    distance[1][1] = elasticity[1] * resistance[1];
    distance[1][2] = elasticity[1] * resistance[2];
```

and so forth. Obviously I can't use anything like the above example, because the values of range1 and range2 are a result of the user's input to elasticity[] and resistance[], and so may be different every time the program runs. I attempted to use a nested for loop, like so:

```
    int distance[range1][range2];

    for(int i = 0; i <= range1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= range2; j++)
        {
            distance[i][j] = elasticity[i] * resistance[j];
        }
    }
```

which, as far as I can tell, *should* work, but Xcode just spat runtime errors at me.

Anyway, I'm not sure what I can do to fix this; the program is supposed to take three values from the user (the minimum + maximum resistance values, and an increment size for the elasticity) in order to calculate the maximum distance of a projectile and output the results in the form of a table.

Help!

Comment: Change both `<=` to simple `<` and this loops will work, also - don't forget to initialize distance properly, it should be `distance[][3]`, not just `distance[][]`

Comment: The declaration of `distance` is extremely important to this question. Please share.

Comment: I edited the second code block to include the declaration of distance[][]

Comment: @Estimack This `int distance[range1][range2];` shouldn't compile if you are using plain C. To allocate the memory for your two dimensional array you have to use [malloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if using plain C, you need to provide constant values for the matrix dimensions (you need to set maximum values for `range1` and `range2`, like this for instance:

```
int distance[200][200];
```

This means the maximum of `range1` and `range2` is 200

Then, in the loop condition, you need to take into account that array indexing is 0-based. Therefore, if you have say, 4 elements in an array, their indexes will be 0, 1, 2 and 3.

So, you need to change your code like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < range1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < range2; j++)
    {
        distance[i][j] = elasticity[i] * resistance[j];
    }
}
```

so that the index is always **less than** the array dimension.

I hope this helps.
Cheers.